# Laravel Error Exception. Array to string Conversion

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to insert multiple row data in two databse table using single click but the only one row inserted .

protected $table = 'biniyojan';

it throw an another error like this:
(Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize(): Argument #1 ($values) must be of type array, string given)
How can i solve this issue??
////Modified Controller//////

```
public function bbcreate(Request $request)
{

    //dd($request->all());
    $biniyojan_details = new BiniyojanDetails();


    $biniyojan = new Biniyojan();
    $biniyojan->details_id = $biniyojan_details->details_id;
    $biniyojan->date =  $request->date;
    $biniyojan->ab =  $request->ab;
    $biniyojan->school =  $request->school;
    $biniyojan->behora =  $request->behora;
    $biniyojan->save();


    $biniyojan_details = new BiniyojanDetails();
    if (!empty($request->school)) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count((array)$request->school); $i++) {
        $biniyojan_details['biniyojan_id'] = $biniyojan->id;
        $biniyojan_details['school'] = $request->school[$i];
        $biniyojan_details['source'] = $request->source[$i];
        $biniyojan_details['kriyakalap'] = $request->kriyakalap[$i];
        //$biniyojan_details->debit_credit = $request->debit_credit[$i];
        //$biniyojan_details->debit_credit_type = $request->debit_credit_type[$i];
        $biniyojan_details['cash'] = $request->cash[$i];
        $biniyojan_details->save();
        }
    }
    return redirect()->back()->with('status', 'Inserted');
}
```

/////View Blade////////

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('bbcreate') }}">
    @csrf
    <div class="form-row col-x1-3">
        <div class="form-group     col-md-2">
            <input type="date" placeholder="मिति" value="@php echo $today; @endphp" name="date[]" class="form-control" id="inputCity" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
            <select id="inputState" placeholder="" name="ab[]" class="form-control" required>
                <option>2079-080</option>
                <option>2078-079</option>
            </select>
        </div>



        <div class="form-group     col-md-2">
            <select id="inputState" name="school[]" class="form-control" required>
                <option selected disabled>स्रोत पाउने संस्था </option>
                @foreach ($school_array as $sch)
                <option value="{{ $sch -> name }}">{{ $sch -> name}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="form-field">
        <div class="form-row col-x1-3">
            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                <select id="source" name="source[]" class="form-control" required>
                    <option selected disabled value="">स्रोत</option>
                    <option>केन्द्र</option>
                    <option>प्रदेश</option>
                    <option>स्थानीय</option>
                    <option>अन्य</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                <select id="kriyakalap" name="kriyakalap[]" class="form-control" required>
                    <option selected disabled>क्रियाकलाप</option>
                    @foreach ($bini as $bi)
                    <option value="{{$bi->kriyakalap}}"> {{$bi->kriyakalap}}</option>
                    @endforeach

                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                <select name="debit_credit[]" id="debit_credit" class="form-control" required>
                    <option selected="selected" disabled>डेबिट / क्रेडिट</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                <select name="debit_credit_type[]" id="debit_credit_type" class="form-control" required>
                    <option selected="selected" disabled>डेबिट / क्रेडिट प्रकार</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                <input type="text" placeholder="रकम" name="cash[]" class="form-control" id="price" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" name="add" id="add" value="+">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row col-x1-3" style="justify-content:left ;">
        <div class="form-group     col-md-2">
            <input type="text" placeholder="ब्यहोरा" name="behora[]" class="form-control" id="behora" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
            <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="राख्नुहोस्" class="btn btn-primary ">

        </div>

        @if (session('status'))
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            {{ session('status') }}
        </div>
        @endif

    </div>
    <div form-row col-x1-3 id="showdata" class="showdata">
        <p class="show_data"></p>
        <p id="showdata" class="showdata"></p>
    </div>
</form>`enter code here`


//////jQuery For Repeat form////////[enter image description here][1]
<!-- form repeat -->

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        var html = '<span><div id="form-field"> <div class="form-row col-x1-3"> <div class="form-group col-md-2"> <select id="source" name="source[]" class="form-control" required> <option selected disabled value="">स्रोत</option> <option>केन्द्र</option> <option>प्रदेश</option> <option>स्थानीय</option> <option>अन्य</option> </select> </div> <div class="form-group col-md-2"> <select id="kriyakalap" name="kriyakalap[]" class="form-control" required> <option selected disabled>क्रियाकलाप</option> @foreach ($bini as $bi) <option value="{{$bi->kriyakalap}}"> {{$bi->kriyakalap}}</option> @endforeach </select> @foreach ($bini as $bi) @endforeach </div> <div class="form-group col-md-2"> <select name="debit_credit[]" id="debit_credit" class="form-control" required> <option selected="selected" disabled>डेबिट / क्रेडिट</option> </select> </div> <div class="form-group col-md-2"> <select name="debit_credit_type[]" id="debit_credit_type" class="form-control" required> <option selected="selected" disabled>डेबिट / क्रेडिट प्रकार</option> </select> </div> <div class="form-group col-md-2"> <input type="text" placeholder="रकम" name="cash[]" class="form-control" id="price" required> </div> <div class="form-group col-md-2"> <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" name="remove" id="remove" value="-"> </div> </div> </div></span>';
        var max = 5;
        var x = 1;
        $("#add").click(function() {
            if (x <= max) {
                $("#form-field").append(html);
                x++;
            }
        })
        $("#form-field").on('click', '#remove', function() {
            $(this).closest('span').remove();
            x--;
        });
    });

</script>

<!-- form repeat -->


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzb3C.png
```

Comment: Where you are getting `Array to string Conversion` error? I mean on which line? And for the second question as the error said define table name in array: `protected $table = ['biniyojan'];`

Comment: When i trying to submit the data, that error occurs. I'm new to Laravel so I don't know, from where that error comes.

Comment: try to debug your php code by adding a die(); in some random spot and see if you get an error. If you don't get the error move the die() to another line in order to find at what line your error occurs. It is obviously an error conversion problem, because a value is expected to be an array but instead you are giving a string. See if the posted values from the form are in an array form.

Comment: For all the select tag you are using array like name="source[]" if you are not looking for multi-select try name="source" that is without array.

Comment: When i remove bracket from the form and insert single data, it works. But i wanted to insert multiple data.

Answer (score 0):

please try this:-

```
public function bbcreate(Request $request){

    $biniyojan_details = new BiniyojanDetails();
    $biniyojan_details->school = $request->school;
    $biniyojan_details->source = $request->source;
    $biniyojan_details->kriyakalap = $request->kriyakalap;
    $biniyojan_details->debit_credit = $request->debit_credit;
    $biniyojan_details->debit_credit_type = $request->debit_credit_type;
    $biniyojan_details->cash = $request->cash;

    $biniyojan_details->save();

    if(!empty($request->school)){
        for($i=0; $i< count($request->school); $i++){
            $biniyojan              = new Biniyojan();
            $biniyojan->details_id  = $biniyojan_details->id;
            $biniyojan->date        = $request->date[$i];
            $biniyojan->ab          = $request->ab[$i];
            $biniyojan->school      = $request->school[$i];
            $biniyojan->behora      = $request->behora[$i];
            $biniyojan->save();

        }

    }
    return redirect()->back()->with('status', 'Inserted');
}
```

Comment: It didn't work. It shows this error.   Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize(): Argument #1 ($values) must be of type array, string given. Any other solutions do you have?

Comment: Please share form html...

Comment: I have added my view blade  code at the top of the controller. You can see it.

Answer (score 0):

As you said you are trying to `insert multiple row data`.

Then You must convert `array` into `json` to store it into database.

Do like this - `json_encode($request->school,true);`

Comment: I added some condition and data inserted but only one row inserted. Code in the top. Please review it and help.